# Jailbreaking iPhone 5

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes, applications, jailbreak

How do I Jailbreak my iPhone 5. It is running the latest supported release of iOS (10.3.3).

Answer (score 1):

There are various custom firmware available for Jailbreaking iPhone 5 running iOS 10.3.3.

I'd direct you to releases section of the iOS Jailbreaking [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOS_jailbreaking#Releases,_2011-present) to see the available firmware for yourself.

A few supported ones for your device (from the aforementioned Wikipedia page) are:

- [h3lix Jailbreak](https://h3lix.tihmstar.net)
- [EtasonJB](https://etasonjb.tihmstar.net)
- [Poenix Jailbreak](https://phoenixpwn.com)

**Note:** I personally do not Jailbreak my iOS devices. Please proceed at your own caution. A Jailbreak can be reverted any time by restoring the original firmware.

Comment: I don’t see any of these working on iOS 10.3.3. Can anyone edit the links to improve / clarify that point? My info is here - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/332286/needed-to-download-cydia-on-ios showing 10.3.3 is no-go for a jailbreak.