# Download Cydia on iOS 10.3.3

Tags: iphone, ios, cydia

I've been trying to download Cydia jailbroken. I only found a Cydia demo. I really need to download Cydia on my iPhone 5 with iOS 10.3.3. Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jailbreak iPhone 5 with 10.1.1](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/266008/jailbreak-iphone-5-with-10-1-1)

Answer (score 1):

A reputable jailbreak was released for iOS 10.3.3: [**Meridian**](https://meridian.sparkes.zone/). However, Cydia and Cydia Substrate are not available or functional. Developers have teased functional prototypes of Cydia on iOS 10.3.3 but no public release has been made.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification - I think my answer exists now only of "watch out when you download software from the internet"